# Receive info regarding the amount of cookies created by other domain

Tags: php, cookies

User visit my site and type into input address of his site.
JQuery send AJAX request to my PHP script and now:
how this PHP script can check the amount of cookies which this domain creates (domain from input) ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I have no idea what your question is, but I think you would like to know if its possible to get the cookies of another domain. Short answer: No

Comment: @HugoDelsing: He says he sends an URL via Ajax to his PHP script, and then he wants to know how many cookies that URL sets. He can test that with cURL, it's server side processing, not client side.

Comment: Yeah i figured it out when I read it for the 9th time to decode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the headers of the connection you create from your server to his website. Every cookie will be a header starting with:

`Set-cookie: ...`

You can look into the use of cURL in PHP and `CURLOPT_NOBODY`. [The user manual is here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).